# How to ask forgiveness?

Tags: allah

Assalamualaikum. I know a lots of people are getting infected and dying because of corona. I said." More people should die because of corona,Amin". Instantly I felt remorseful and regret what I said. I want to ask forgiveness from Allah. I know death happens by Almighty's wish. But will I be responsible for someone's death since I wished them? Please tell me some way.......

Comment: I have been waiting for my answer for 8 hours. Will you please feel responsible enough to answer my question which I asked 8 hours ago?

Answer (score 1):

You should never make this type of Dua for anyone. If you can't wish good for anyone don't wish bad at least. Repentance is act of worship which Allah loves most. If you think you have sinned ask forgiveness from Allah, be humble and try not to do this again. Have faith in Allah. insha'Allah you will be forgiven. Jazakallah Khairan